# Android receive and send message

Tags: android

I Have 1 activity and 1 ordinary class, which activity one to receive message and ordinary class to send message. How to implement it:

In ActivityOne.class

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    public mHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            switch (msg.what) {
                case 10:
                   Toast("Get message 10");
                   break;
                case 1:
                   Toast("Get message 1");
                   break;
            }
        }
    };
}

public void Toast(String text) {
    Toast.makeText(ActivityOne.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And in Ordinary.class

> How code to sendEmptyMessage(1) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use it

**EDIT:**

```
public class TestApplication extends Application{

private Handler handler = null;  

    public void setHandler(Handler handler) { this.handler = handler; }  
    public Handler getHandler() { return handler; }  
}
```

then in ActivityOne

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            switch (msg.what) {
                case 10:
                   Toast("Get message 10");
                   break;
                case 1:
                   Toast("Get message 1");
                   break;
            }
        }
    };
    TestApplication mAPP = (TestApplication) getApplication(); 
    mAPP.setHandler(mHandler);  
}
```

ActivityTwo

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_two);
    TestApplication mAPP = (TestApplication) getApplication(); 
    mAPP.getHandler().sendEmptyMessage(1);

}
```

and you must be fix the AndroidManifest.xml add **android:name=".TestApplication"**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:name=".TestApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

**EDIT2:**

you also can use the above code in ordinary classse or something like this:

```
public class ordinary{
    private Handler handler = null;  

    public ordinary(Handler handler) { this.handler = handler; }  
    public void doSomeThing(){
        handler .sendEmptyMessage(1);
    }
}
```

in ActivityOne:

```
ordinary clazz = new ordinary(mHandler);
clazz.doSomeThing();
```

**EDIT END**

Comment: @HaicalRams !sorry,let me try

Comment: Hi, how to if ActivityTwo not activity, just ordinary class. I just edit my question. Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34041/discussion-between-haical-rams-and-zt9788)

Comment: @HaicalRams I do not undersatand about you mean~